# How to auto update android application without distribute in appstore?

Tags: java, android, app-store, apk, auto-update

How my application can get auto updates for my specific clients for testing before launch to the appstore. i want to host my app somewhere from where my installed app on some selected clients can get auto updates for testing instead of all the time install for each person mobile manually.

Comment: Are you building your own custom ROM? If not, what you want is not possible. Users are involved in all app installs and upgrades.

Comment: we have many testers to test our app after some updates and each time after i update i have to install app for each tester manually. if there is any way to update there app automatically by hosting my app somewhere else or any alternative way.

Comment: Other than through the official channel for the device (e.g., Play Store for Google Play devices), all apps installs/upgrades involve user approval. As Chau Thai notes, you can use private channels on the Play Store.

Comment: In google play store you have the possibility to upload an alpha or betatest application. You can invite selected people to install the app with  play store. Then you have your auto sync.

Comment: Ok got it thanks all of you for your great help.

Answer (score 2):

You can upload your apk into alpha or beta testing channel on Google Play. This way the app is not publish on Google Play and only registered tester (which you add/invite them) can get app. It also auto updates the app for testers when you push a new version into the testing channel.

Comment: ok i have never registered yet for appstore . but you said i have option for testing in appstore so then i will go and register in appstore thanks for the solution.